# What causes Python to complain about catting list to list in code with no lists?

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

In a file I wrote (stripped down from actual code)

```
e = numpy.zeros(4)
n = e.copy()
n[0]=e[0]
for i in range(len(e)-1)+1:
    n[i] = n[i-1]*e[i] + e[i]
```

When I run the .py file, Python says:

```
>>> for i in range(len(e)-1)+1:
...     n[i] = n[i-1]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Oddly, if I paste `"i=1"` (or other value) and the one line that does actual work into the Python prompt, there's no error.  In any case, I don't see any lists; it's all numpy arrays.

Comment: The `for` line is your problem.

Comment: This is not a good brain day for me.  I even misspelled Python!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
range(len(e)-1) + 1
```

This is concatenating an int (`1`) to a list (`range(...)`).

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
for i in range(1, len(e)):
```